# Approximation for interpolation of harmonic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-algorithms

I need a good approximations for $H_p$, for $p \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, the generalization of $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ to the real numbers.

I tried $H_p = p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k (k + p)}$ and $H_p = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j (1 + k)^{-2 - j} p^{1 + j}$ for $-\frac{1}{2}<p<\frac{1}{2}$, both converge very slow, just five digit of $H_\frac{1}{2}$ take ~1,000,000 iterations.

Comment: What do you mean with $H(p)$?

Comment: Possibly the generalization of the harmonic number $H_n=1+1/2+\dots+1/n$ to noninteger $n$ given by $H_x=\sum_{n\ge1}(1/n-1/(n+x))$?

Comment: If so, for rational $0<p<1$ you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments has an explicit formular for $H_\frac{p}{q}$, though the approximations for cos, ln,... will be annoying, I'll update the question once I implemented it

Comment: Doesn't the Wikipedia section on [computing the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_and_approximation) (together with an approximation of the Euler-Mascheroni constant) contain all the information you need on how to compute $H(p) = \psi(p+1) + \gamma$ to any given precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can compute $H_p = p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k (k + p)}$ very fast and very accurately as follows. Let
\begin{equation*}
    f(x):=\frac p{(x+1)(x+1 + p)}=\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1+p},
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    H_p=\sum_{k=0}^c f(k)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_c(k),
\end{equation*}
where $c$ is a natural number and $f_c(x):=f(c+x)$.

If $c$ is large enough, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_c(k)$ can be evaluated fast with high precision by the Euler--Maclaurin (EM) formula:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_c(k)=-G_{m,c}+R_{m,c},  
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
G_{m,c}:=   F(c) 
    + \frac{f(c)}2  
    +
    \sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\frac{B_{2j}}{(2j)!}f^{(2j-1)}(c), 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    F(x):=\ln\frac{x+1}{x+1+p} 
\end{equation*}
(so that $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ with $F(\infty-)=0$), $m$ is a natural number, the $B_k$'s are the Bernoulli numbers, and
\begin{equation*}
    |R_{m,c}|<\frac{2.02}{(2\pi)^{2m-1}}f^{(2m-2)}(c) \\ 
    =\frac{2.02(2m-2)!}{(2\pi)^{2m-1}}((c+1)^{1-2m}-((c+1+p)^{1-2m}) 
\end{equation*}
if $m\ge4$.

If we want to get $H(p)$ with $d$ correct decimal digits after the decimal point, then good choices for $m$ and $c$ are as follows:
\begin{equation*}
    m=\Big\lceil\frac d{2\log_{10}d}\Big\rceil,\quad 
    c=\Big\lceil\frac1{\pi e}\,m\,10^{d/(2m)}\Big\rceil; 
\end{equation*}
see [Section 6.1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-018-0978-y) for details or [Section 6.1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-018-0978-y) for more details.

E.g., if we want to get $H(2/3)$ with $1000$ correct decimal digits after the decimal point, then we can choose $m=167$ and $c=19288$, so that the error $|R_{m,c}|$ of the corresponding  approximation
\begin{equation*}
    H_{2/3;m,c}:=\sum_{k=0}^c f(k)-G_{m,c} 
\end{equation*}
of $H(2/3)$ is $<3\times10^{-1002}$. This approximation, $H_{2/3;m,c}$, of $H(2/3)$ was computed by Mathematica in just about $0.11$ sec. Since $H_{2/3}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3 \ln3}{2}$, we find that the actual difference $H_{2/3;m,c}-H_{2/3}$ between the approximate and true values is $\approx-3.08\times10^{-1003}$. The corresponding Mathematica notebook can be viewed [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ipinelis/Published/1.nb).

---

Using the [summation formula](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-018-0978-y) alternative to the EM formula, we can parallelize calculations and thus further reduce the execution time if the desired number $d$ of correct digits is large enough (such as $2000$ or more).

Comment: For p=2/3 you should test H(2/3) against the closed form value 3/2+1/6*Pi*3^(1/2)-3/2*ln(3). This gives 0.7589812491149**4438820** ... which is different from 0.7589812491149**28906960** ...

Comment: @JorgeZuniga : Thank you for your comment. There were two typos in my Mathematica notebook, which are now fixed, so that all the $1000$ digits are now correct.